# How do I convert vector to single text?

Tags: r

```
a <- c("SPY US Equity", "IVV US Equity", "AGG US Equity")
```

I can get a result like

```
[1] "SPY US Equity" "IVV US Equity" "AGG US Equity"
```

I want to get in one string like this

```
"SPY US Equity", "IVV US Equity", "AGG US Equity"
```

I Used `paste()`

```
paste(a,collapse=" , ")
[1] "SPY US Equity , IVV US Equity , AGG US Equity"
```

but the result is not what I want.

How do I can get

```
"SPY US Equity", "IVV US Equity", "AGG US Equity"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` taking care of `"` and `'`:

```
paste0('"', paste(a, sep = ",", collapse = '", "'), '"')
```

Corresponding to:

```
"\"SPY US Equity\", \"IVV US Equity\", \"AGG US Equity\""
```

Wich is using `View` :

```
"SPY US Equity", "IVV US Equity", "AGG US Equity"
```

Answer (score 3):

R provides a convenience function for quoting strings:

```
message = paste(dQuote(a), collapse = ', ')
```

This will use “smart” quotes if R thinks your output device supports them:

```
message(result)
# “SPY US Equity”, “IVV US Equity”, “AGG US Equity”
```

If you want to force using “dumb”/straight quotes, do

```
options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)
```

before using `dQuote`.